# Remove confirmable from Devise (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am editing an app that I made few months ago, and I have Devise installed in it with `:confirmable` enabled. I wanted to remove confirmable from my app, but my db schema already have confirmable built-in many migrations ago, and it is almost impossible to have a smooth rollbacks.

How can I remove confirmable from my app and allow user to sign up right away without having to click on confirmation email link? If it is impossible, is there a workaround?

```
User model:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :login
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  ...

Schema:

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    ...
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove `confirmable` from the parameters to `devise` method in `user.rb`

And also remove the columns `confirmation_token`, `confirmed_at`, `confirmation_sent_at` and  `unconfirmed_email` using migrations as they are no longer needed.

Comment: Sorry to repeat what you just said, but you're referring to deleting `:confirmable` from ` devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable` list on User model, correct?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Updated my answer